# Convertir filas de una tabla HTML en lsita de objetos dentro de un JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Tengo un formulario HTML, el cual convierto en JSON para después enviarlo al servidor. El formulario es el siguiente:

```
{% extends "base2.html" %}
{% block title %}Generar cupo{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<br>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style_formularios.css">
    <style>
        .container {
            font-size: 18px;
            align-self: stretch;
            margin-left: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        /* MOBILE */
        @media (max-width: 865px) {
            .col-sm {
                position: static;
            }

            .mb-3 {
                position: static;
            }

            .col {
                position: inherit;
            }

            .container {
                width: min-content;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div id="msj_error" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none; position: static;
font-size: 18px; text-align: center;">

</div>
<form id="frm" action="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"> 
                <div class="padre">
                    <div class="contenedor">
                        <div class="contenedor">
                            {{form.empresa.label}}
                            {{form.empresa(style="width=10px")}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="contenedor">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="contenedor">
                                        <label>Tipo orden</label>
                                        {% for radio_btn in form.tipo_despacho %}
                                        <div style="margin-left: 10%;">
                                            {{ radio_btn(class="form-check-input", style="position: inherit;
                                            margin-left: -12.25rem;") }}
                                            {{radio_btn.label(class="form-check-label", style="padding-left: 10px;}")}}
                                        </div>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="contenedor">
                                        <label>A despachar</label>
                                        {% for radio_btn in form.a_despachar %}
                                        <div style="margin-left: 10%;">
                                            {{ radio_btn(class="form-check-input", style="position: inherit;
                                            margin-left: -12.25rem;") }}
                                            {{radio_btn.label(class="form-check-label", style="padding-left: 10px;}")}}
                                        </div>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="div-despachos-envase" class="contenedor">
                            {{form.despacho.label}}
                            {{form.despacho}}
                            {{form.envases.label}}
                            {{form.envases}}
                        </div>
                        <div id="div-carga-maxima" class="contenedor">
                            {{form.kilos_o_unidades.label}}
                            {{form.kilos_o_unidades}} <label for="kilos_o_unidades" id="lbl_kilos_o_unidades"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contenedor">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    {{form.cant_cupos_iguales.label}}
                                    {{form.cant_cupos_iguales(style="width: 50px; float")}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="padre">
                    <div class="contenedor">
                        <div class="contenedor">
                            <table class="table table-sm table-light table-bordered" id="tabla_productos_envases">
                                <thead class="thead-dark">
                                    <tr style="align-content: center;">
                                        <th id="header_producto_envase">Producto</th>
                                        <th id="header_porcentaje_unidad" style="width: 185px;">Porcentaje</th>
                                        <th>Opciones</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="primer_row_tabla" style="vertical-align:middle;">
                                            {{form.productos_0(class="form-select", style="width: 182px;")}}</td>
                                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
                                            <div class="input-group mb-3" style="margin-bottom: 0rem!important;">
                                                <input id="input_porcentaje_unidades_0"
                                                    name="input_porcentaje_unidades_0" type="number"
                                                    class="form-control" placeholder="Porcentaje"
                                                    aria-label="Porcentaje" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                                                    style="width: 110px; position: static;" min="1" max="100" />
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text"
                                                        id="signo_porcentaje_unidad_input">%</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="vertical-align:middle; padding: 2px;">
                                            <img onclick="insertRowInTable();" src="/static/plus.png" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contenedor">
                            {{form.obs.label}}
                            {{form.obs(cols=25, rows=6 )}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="contenedor">
                            {{form.btn_guardar(class="btn btn-primary")}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script src="/static/prueba.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Esta es la funcion en la cual convierto el formulario en JSON:

```
//prueba meter todos los datos del frm en un json
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var miForm = document.getElementById('frm');
    miForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData(this);
      console.log(formData)
      var jsonData = {};
      for (var [k, v] of formData) {
        jsonData[k] = v;
      }
      console.log(jsonData);
    }
  
  });
```

Este es el JSON que obtengo

```
a_despachar: "F"
cant_cupos_iguales: "1"
despacho: "6;S"
empresa: "36"
envases: "97"
input_porcentaje_unidades_0: "10"
input_porcentaje_unidades_1: "80"
input_porcentaje_unidades_2: "10"
kilos_o_unidades: "30000"
obs: "No obs"
productos_0: "14;1098.42"
productos_1: "75;0"
productos_2: "29;3.46"
tipo_despacho: "D"
```

El problema surge a continuación: el usuario puede agregar X cantidad de productos en la tabla HTML. Dichos productos están representados por los inputs "productos_X" que es el select html que me da el codigo del producto y por "input_porcentaje_unidades_X" que me da el porcentaje o la cantidad del producto que solicita el cliente. Yo necesitaria representar los productos como "una lista de objetos" por así decir, dentro del JSON, de esta manera, podría trabajarlos en el backend independientemente de la cantidad de productos que cargue el cliente. Ejemplo del JSON que necesitaría obtener:

```
a_despachar: "F"
cant_cupos_iguales: "1"
despacho: "6;S"
empresa: "36"
envases: "97"
kilos_o_unidades: "30000"
obs: "No obs"
tipo_despacho: "D"
productos: [
{
    cod_prod:"14;1098.42"
    porcentaje_unidades: 10
},
{
    cod_prod:"75;0"
    porcentaje_unidades: 80
},
{
    cod_prod:"29;3.46"
    porcentaje_unidades:10
},
]
```